# Understanding the renormalization process in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, regularization

I am having problems understanding the process of regularization and renormalization in quantum field theory. As far as I understand it, this process of taming the infinites could be summarized in the following steps:

1. At first, we try to compute something like $i\mathcal{M}$ from a Feynman diagram, but it can happen that the integrals appearing finally diverge, for example, because some loops cannot be compensated.
2. We then try to assign a value to such divergent diagrams, which is called regularization. This can be done in multiple ways depending of how suitable the different methods are for the different theories. For example, regularization via UV cutoff, or dimensional regularization.
3. Finally, we absorb the divergent parts of the result from regularization into the parameters of our theory, like masses or coupling constants, and generate counterterms in our lagrangian, such that this new version does not present the problem with divergences. This process is the renormalization part, and it can also be done in multiple ways.

From here, I have two questions. First, when I see a renormalized lagrangian sometimes I see factors like, for example, $Z_m$, and others, $\delta_m$. Which is the relationship between $Z_m$ and $\delta_m$ if there is any? My intuition is that factors of the form $\delta$ are usually related to the counterterms, while $Z$ seems to be used to absorb its corresponding $\delta$ and write a lagrangian with the same form as the original previous to renormalization.

Finally, when I see some exercises on regularization or listen to my professor, it seems like it is clear in which counterterms the resulting regularization should be absorbed, but I am not able to see why. Let me take as an example the $\lambda\phi^4$ theory: how do one knows which terms I should renormalize (mass?, coupling constant?) after the regularization process in the $1$-loop correction of the propagator?

I would appreciate any help on understanding this.

Comment: Are you following a reference? Which page?

Comment: I suggest you consult a textbook, where these things are usually explained in detail. Peskin & Schroeder is a good start.